# Trouble subtracting dates in JS

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I'm running this code in my vue component from a datepicker which returns the dates as shown in my data below.

Everything is good, except for when I console.log the `days` variable it's 0 when it should definitely be a larger number

Am I converting it incorrectly?

```js
var vm = 
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
    date_test1:'2021-02-02',
    date_test2:'2021-05-15'
  },
  methods: {
    
    testDate(){
      
      const diff_in_days = Math.abs(new Date(date_test1) - new Date(date_test2));
      
      const days = Math.ceil(diff_in_days / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));

      console.log(days);
    }
  }
  
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
```

Comment: Try console.log `date_test1` and `date_test2` and you should know why.

Comment: I can confirm that the date subtracting logic is correct so you might want to look at something else. For example, and in methods, you need to use `this.$data.date_test1`

Comment: Prefix dates with "vm.data."